# SQLite query to get records with certain condition

Tags: qt, sqlite, qt5

My SQLite table name is Invoices, having columns Part Number and Manufacturer.

My problem is to query the table in such a manner that it shows only records where part number have at least 2 different unique manufacturers.

I researched the stack over flow and I tried this solution

```
QString Filter = "PART_NUMBER in (select PART_NUMBER FROM Invoices GROUP BY "
         "PART_NUMBER HAVING count(PART_NUMBER)>1)";
model->setFilter(Filter);
model->select();
```

But this solution's problem is it shows part number having same manufacturer also.

Edit:

[image]

In this example it should return part 2 only

Comment: So your table has multiple entries with same part number and manufacturer? Please provide an example of your data.

Comment: @MartinHennings I have updated now

Comment: Does your table contain additional columns? Or (if not) do you use the table to count parts by manufacturer, inserting a new row for each used part?

Comment: @MartinHennings Yes my table contains additional columns. I have separate column as unique key column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count `Manufacturer`:

```
select PART_NUMBER FROM Invoices GROUP BY "
     "PART_NUMBER HAVING count(MANUFACTURER)>1
```

---

Ok, so you're saying that your data looks like this:

```
PART_NUMBER | MANUFACTURER
      1     |      A
      2     |      A
      2     |      A (duplicate entry)
      3     |      A
      3     |      B
      4     |      A
      4     |      B
```

Then you'd need to select `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(MANUFACTURER))`.

In sqlite, this looks a bit more complex:

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(MANUFACTURER) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MANUFACTURER FROM Table WHERE ...);
> ```

See [this blog post](http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=690).

But that's more than QSqlQueryModel can do with `setFilter(...)`.

This problem looks like a database design issue. Do you know about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)?

When you've normalized your tables, the problem becomes significantly simplified.

Comment: That doesn't take into consideration of unique manufacturer. It just returns part number which have multiple entries

Comment: I certainly don't know about database normalisation. Let me check the new solution thanks!